# Efficient debugging Django with pdb – like Sentry

Tags: django, sentry, pdb

I use pdb to debug in Django. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not catch the issue, just runs over the error. I have another example, the way how Sentry shows the bugs. Exactly at the place where it is relevant. Could I use pdb similarly? Maybe via the "where" command? It would be so useful!

An example: if there is a bug in one of the serializers, it is so hard to find the relevant code place. Django server just gives a *"non_field_errors":["Something unexpected has occured. Please contact an admin to fix this issue."]*. On the other hand, Sentry can show the hot spot. So it "can" be found. I would like to find it with pdb also!

Comment: Would [pdb.post_mortem()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.post_mortem) help?
Add it to the top-level exception handler to print the traceback, which should give you a clue where the error originated from.

Comment: You gave the solution!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!
Also posted a more detailed answer with a demo script for the future readers' convenience.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [pdb.post_mortem()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.post_mortem). It can be placed in a top level exception handler, and it will show a full traceback, effectively revealing where an exception deep in the call stack actually occurred.

Example script (named **test.py**):

```py
import pdb


def main():
    foo()

def foo():
    bar()

def bar():
    baz()

def baz():
    x = 5
    y = 0
    return x / y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception:
        print("Exception caught in top level exception handler")
        pdb.post_mortem()
```

Running the script drops us into a post-mortem debugger:

```
$ python test.py
Exception caught in top level exception handler
> /home/peter/.../test.py(16)baz()
-> return x / y
(Pdb)
```

The error occurred in line 16 in the `baz()` function in module `test.py`.

We can also use the pdb's `list` command to reveal additional context:

```
(Pdb) l
 11         baz()
 12  
 13     def baz():
 14         x = 5
 15         y = 0
 16  ->     return x / y
 17  
 18  
 19     if __name__ == "__main__":
 20         try:
 21             main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer with pdb.post_mortem() into top-level exception handler (of @plamut) was great – it worked! Thanks really!!

I've put an intentional error into a serializer and it was found without a breakpoint. The top-level exception handler (in this Django system) was main/exception_handler.py.